# How to remove padding between Xaxis and the chart of a vertical chart in rechart and also It is not appliyng color coorectly?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

**Problem:**

I am creating a chart component using recharts in my react application.

This is my code.

```
import React, { Component, PureComponent } from "react";

import { Card, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import {
  Bar,
  BarChart,
  Tooltip,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  ResponsiveContainer,
  Cell,
  LabelList
} from "recharts";

import "./SubcribersByRegion.css";

const colors = [
  "#138185",
  "#26a0a7",
  "#65d3da",
  "#79d69f",
  "#cbe989",
  "#ebf898",
  "#f9ec86",
  "#fad144",
  "#ec983d",
  "#d76c6c"
];

const data = [
  {
    name: "Page A",
    pv: 2400,
    amt: 2400
  },
  {
    name: "Page B",
    pv: 1398,
    amt: 2210
  },
  {
    name: "Page C",
    pv: 9800,
    amt: 2290
  },
  {
    name: "Page D",
    pv: 3908,
    amt: 2000
  },
  {
    name: "Page E",
    pv: 4800,
    amt: 2181
  },
  {
    name: "Page F",
    pv: 3800,
    amt: 2500
  },
  {
    name: "Page G",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  },
  {
    name: "Page H",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  },
  {
    name: "Page I",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  },
  {
    name: "Page J",
    pv: 4300,
    amt: 2100
  }
];

class SubcribersByRegion extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Card className="subscribers-by-region-card">
          <CardTitle className="subscribers-by-region-card-title">
            Subscribers by Region
          </CardTitle>
          <CardBody>
            <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%" aspect={6.5 / 8.9}>
              <BarChart
                data={data}
                layout="vertical"
                barGap={4}
                margin={{
                  top: 27,
                  right: 5,
                  left: 5,
                  bottom: 0
                }}
              >
                <Tooltip />
                <XAxis className="xaxies" />
                <Bar
                  dataKey="pv"
                  fill="#8884d8"
                  maxBarSize={10}
                >
                  {data.map((entry, index) => (
                    <Cell key={`cell-${index+1}`} fill={colors[index]} />
                  ))}
                  <LabelList dataKey="pv" position="right" />
                </Bar>
              </BarChart>
            </ResponsiveContainer>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SubcribersByRegion;
```

This is how my chart looks like now.

[image]

The tried to find a solution for why this is not showing the bar for the first element. And also I tried many ways like adding styling to Xaxias for removing the padding between xAxis and the chart. But I was unable to find any solution for It. Can someone help me to find out a solution to this problem by modifying my code? Thank you!!

Comment: something went wrong there, the x-axis bar below is showing number like displaying in vertical not horizontal. I mean it should be vertical chart, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Kai I want to show the bar directions like in the above image. So it should be verticle.

Comment: I know, but I think the configuration maybe wrong some where :D. Just my opinion, if everything is correct, so it should be like this.